# Azure DevOps Pipelines - Python - ModuleNotFoundError despite sys.path.append() or setting PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, azure-devops, pythonpath

I'm trying to run some tests for my python application but I'm not able to set the path correctly so that my `test.py` can find it.

My Application is structured like this:

```
repo/src/main/python/main_module
repo/tests/test.py
```

And my `test.py` is looking like this:

```
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.normpath('C:/repo/src/main/python'))
import main_module
```

Now I want to test the code within Azure Pipelines, so first I copy the repo in place:

```
- powershell: |
    cd C:/
    mkdir repo
    cp -r -v $(src.repo)/* C:/repo/
  condition: eq( variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT' )
```

After that I use `tree` to test if everything was copied correctly.

And then I simply run the test script by calling:

```
python C:/repo/tests/test.py
```

But that gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I've also tried setting the path to my `main_module` via PYTHONPATH but that's not working too.

Is their something I missed or is this a bug within Azure Pipelines?

Comment: does your `main_module` dir contains `__init__.py` file?

Comment: Yes it does. And on my local machine everything works just fine.

Comment: can you do `python C:/repo/src/main/python/main_module/__init__.py` on the remote machine?

Comment: Yes that works fine

Comment: can you post the exact traceback you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking to the Azure DevOps Support, I now know that my issue is a bug within DevOps-Pipelines at the moment.

For now I'm going to copy my test-scripts next to my main module and delete them if everything was successful and before building the application.

Comment: any further info you can provide (comms from support or link to issue), i am seeing my PYTHONPATH export ignored when it works locally and this is over a year later

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Is there a ticket link for the bug?

Comment: Any update here?  Having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To execute python script with Azure pipeline in Linux enviroment, I used 'script:'

```
script: pythonpath=/repo/src/main/python python3 repo/tests/test.py 
displayName: 'execute script python'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the symptoms I believe this is the same issue as:
[Azure pipeline can't find the user created python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61639935/azure-pipeline-cant-find-the-user-created-python-module/)

I have solved it with the following workaround

> include a script in the pipeline to move the source code into a new
> suitably named directory and then test it there.

See my answer to the other question for full details and example YAML

Answer (score 0):

This worked as a bash script in my Azure Pipeline, assuming `path/to/src` contains your user-defined module:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PYTHONPATH;]$PYTHONPATH:$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/path/to/src"
```

Note that the new `PYTHONPATH` is not available until the subsequent step.