# Azure pipeline can't find the user created python module

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, pytest

I am attempting to run tests from a python module using Azure DevOps. I've got a pipeline build set up to build of a yml file and also using classic editor. I'm getting an error that my module name on my imports is not right. When I run this locally, it works just fine.

**My Repo structure:**

[image: Here is my repo structure]

**I'm running my test using this command as a batch file:**

*cd testcases*

*pytest -v test_msoffice.py*

**and gives me error:**

```
______________________ ERROR collecting test_msoffice.py ______________________
ImportError while importing test module 'D:\a\1\s\testcases\test_msoffice.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test_msoffice.py:7: in <module>
    from util import utility_method_class
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named util
```

Someone please help me.

Comment: Try `python -m pytest -v testcases/test_msoffice.py` from the project directory (e.g. one directory up).

Comment: Where is the `__init__.py` file? If it is in the test folder, try deleting it.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yes, by using python -m, error is gone. But why this?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I don't have __init__.py file anywhere.

Comment: `python -m` adds the current path to the Python path, so `util` will be found as a top level module.

Comment: Thanks @MrBeanBremen but when I execute it in my local, it executes without python -m.Is it something with Azure pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same symptoms over the last two days.
I assume locally your package is in a directory called *"util"*, with (or as per your comment without) an `__init__.py` file. This leads python to recognise all modules under that directory as belonging to the utils package. (From Python 3.something python will manage "namespace references" to the local directory structure without `__init__.py`)
On the Pipeline agent the code is directly copied into D:\a\1\s\ - therefore python will consider the package to be called *"s"*

I found the following workaround: **include a script in the pipeline to move the source code into a new suitably named directory and then test it there**.

My Pipeline YAML looks like this. It is based on the assumption that your ADO project is named the same as your package - so in your case *"util"* and is set up for ubuntu / bash. If you must test on windows agents then the scripting will need porting, or you can switch to ubuntu agents and copy the whole thing.

```
# Python package
# Create and test a Python package on multiple Python versions.
# Add steps that analyze code, save the dist with the build record, publish to a PyPI-compatible index, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python

trigger:
- azure-pipelines
- master
- pipeline/*

variables:
  PythonPackagePath: ORIGINALVALUE

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    # Python27:
    #   python.version: '2.7'
    # Python35:
    #  python.version: '3.5'
    # Python36:
    #   python.version: '3.6'
    # Python37:
    #   python.version: '3.7'
    Python310:
      python.version: '3.10'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    export ParentDir=${PWD%/*}

    echo Setting PythonPackagePath to $ParentDir/$(System.TeamProject)
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PythonPackagePath;]$ParentDir/$(System.TeamProject)"

  displayName: 'Set Package Path'

- script: |
    echo PythonPackagePath is $(PythonPackagePath)
    
    echo Moving files from $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) to $(PythonPackagePath)
    mv $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) $(PythonPackagePath)

    echo SymLinking old Working Directory back in case needed
    ln -s $(PythonPackagePath) $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    ls -l $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/..
  displayName: 'Move Working Directory'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'
  # continueOnError: true

- script: |
    export PYTHONPATH=$(PythonPackagePath)
    echo PYTHONPATH is set to $PYTHONPATH

    cd $(PythonPackagePath)
    echo Working in:
    pwd

    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
    pip install pytest-cov
    pytest --cov=. --cov-report=xml
  displayName: 'pytest'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(PythonPackagePath)/**/coverage.xml'
```

A few traps I fell into along the way:

1. ADO pipeline variables of the form `$(VariableName)` are resolved when the step starts, not when the line is reached - so you need to set the variable in a *previous step* before using it.
2. bash will keep a relative directory reference in place in a variable. So you cannot `export ParentDir=..` nor `export ParentDir=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/..` in the first case ParentDir is always the parent of the current working directory, in the second the symlinking will fail due to circular references. The RegEx `${PWD%/*}` gets the value of the current directory and returns the value up to the last slash.
3. pytest does not like following symlinks - so you cannot simply `ln -s path/to/code/s path/to/code/PackageName` pytest will still consider the package to be called *s*
4. Setting `PYTHONPATH` is not strictly necessary, running pytest from the right directory seems to be the most stable option in thie configuration
5. I had a few issues with getting code coverage to publish properly. I think it also doesn't like symlinks - so don't forget to update the path in the relevant step as well.

This works regardless of whether tests are in a subfolder. My overall structure is:

```
FooBar
      __init__.py
    ¦
    -- Doomsday
      __init__.py
      Fuel.py
      test_Fuel.py
      ...
    ¦
    -- Utils
          __init__.py
          Maths.py
          ...
        ¦
        --test
              test_Maths1.py
              test_Maths2.py
              ...
```

where:

- FooBar is also the name of my project in ADO
- pytest tests for Doomsday are in the Doomsday directory
- pytest tests for Utils are in a subfolder
- references are in the form `from FooBar.Utils.Maths import prod` and these work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is related to [Azure DevOps Pipelines - Python - ModuleNotFoundError despite sys.path.append() or setting PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54506978/2142577), where it says:

> After talking to the Azure DevOps Support, I now know that my issue is a bug within DevOps-Pipelines at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue recently and found a very simple solution to it.
The issue is at least present on Azure DevOps agents running on Windows machines. I have not validated if the issue is present on Linux machines.

The issue is that Windows DevOps agents is using backslash i paths for $(Build.SourcesDirectory) or $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) and backslash is treated as escape character in the import command causing all kind of issues.

**A simple solution to this is to replace the backslash with forward slash in the path:**

(In this example I am importing the _version.py file and save the __version__ parameter as variable in the pipeline):

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: 'Retrieve software version'
  inputs:
    scriptSource: inline
    script: |
      import sys
      path = r"$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
      path = path.replace("\\", "/")
      sys.path.append(path)

      from _version import __version__
      print("SW version: ", __version__)
      print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable=SwVersion]{__version__}')
```